# Sendgrid API section tags do not render | Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

I am using the Sendgrid npm package to send emails.  I currently have a template set up on Sendgrid. When I make a call using the API the email is sent but the dynamic content is not populated.

I am following the params per this documentation: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Build/Add_Content/substitution_and_section_tags.html

```
 {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/v3/mail/send',
        body: {
            personalizations: [{
                to: [{
                    email: params.sendTo
                }],
                subject: params.subject
            }],
            from: {
                email: params.sendFrom
            },
            content: [{
                    type: 'text/plain',
                    value: params.plainMessage
                },
                {
                    type: 'text/html',
                    value: params.htmlMessage
                }
            ],
            template_id: params.templateId,
            "substitutions": {
                "{{name}}": "Matt"
            },
            asm: {
                group_id: params.group_id ? params.group_id : 3187,
                groups_to_display: params.groups_to_display ? params.groups_to_display : null
            }
        }
    }
```

Then on the sendgrid client I simply have an HTML template where I call {{name}} inside the transactional emails.

The email itself makes it, but the "handlebar tag" is not rendering the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had stuck the substitutions tag in the wrong order of the params object

```
 {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/v3/mail/send',
        body: {
            personalizations: [{
                to: [{
                    email: params.sendTo
                }],
                subject: params.subject,
                "substitutions": {
                "{{name}}": "Matt"
                },
            }],
            from: {
                email: params.sendFrom
            },
            content: [{
                    type: 'text/plain',
                    value: params.plainMessage
                },
                {
                    type: 'text/html',
                    value: params.htmlMessage
                }
            ],
            template_id: params.templateId,
            asm: {
                group_id: params.group_id ? params.group_id : 3187,
                groups_to_display: params.groups_to_display ? params.groups_to_display : null
            }
        }
    }
```